# c++ find command no longer works

Tags: c++, list, iterator, find

This is some old code not written by me. It compiles with GCC 3.4.6, but now we are checking the build with GCC 4.4.7 and the build fails.

I hope this code is enough to go on:

```
list<Chapter*>  * tocP;   //Chapter is a class

tocP = NULL;
if (_searchChapter)
{
_chapter = _manager->GetCurrentChapter();   // _chapter is a Chapter*
}
else
{
tocP = _manager->GetTableOfContents();

if (tocP != NULL && tocP->size() > 0)
    _chapter = tocP->front();
}
...

list<Chapter*>::iterator chp;

if (tocP != NULL && tocP->size() > 0)
for (chp=find(tocP->begin(),tocP->end(),_chapter); chp != tocP->end(); ++chp)  // this code fails
{
   //code to process chapter
}
```

error message is:

../src/HelpSearchC.C: In member function 'int HelpSearchC_i::DoSearch()':
../src/HelpSearchC.C:685: error: no matching function for call to 'find(std::_List_iterator<Chapter*>, 
std::_List_iterator<Chapter*>, Chapter*&)'

Comment: Did you `#include <algorithm>`?

Comment: Well that was sure fast!! Thanks very much. Problem gone.

Comment: So GCC 3.4.6 just pulls in the definition of the find algorithm without the need to #include <algorithm>?

Comment: Perhaps `<algorithm>` was included by some other header, which changed with a newer GCC release.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `#include <algorithm>` on top of the file. The function [find](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find/) is defined within this header.